# Finding the radius of convergence of $\sum\frac{{(n!)}^2{z}^n}{{(2n)!}} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Using the ratio test, I keep getting a radius of convergence of $\left| z \right| < 2$, when the answer is 4. What leads to the answer of 4?

Comment: I assume you meant $n\to\infty$ rather than $i\to\infty$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\lvert\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right\rvert&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\dfrac{(n+1)!}{n!}\right]^2\cdot\dfrac{(2n)!}{(2n+2)!}\vert z\vert\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}&\dfrac{(n+1)^2}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}\vert z\vert
\end{eqnarray}

so clearly the limit goes to $\left\lvert\dfrac{z}{4}\right\rvert<1$.

So $\vert z\vert<4$

Comment: Ah thanks for that. I didn't distribute the 2 in (2(n+1))! in the denominator which explains my error. Thanks!